# Left Monitor Disables on Login

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and ever since getting two new 32" Dell curved monitors the left screen will be disabled every time I log back into or restart my computer. More specifically, it will initially all load correctly on login, then after about a second both screens will flash back and only the right one will come back on. I checked the display settings and for some reason the it's setting the left monitor to "Disabled" despite being still properly plugged in and powered on and switching the right monitor to primary. I can fix this by either changing the settings back manually or unplugging and replugging either monitor cable. (The left monitor uses DisplayPort, the right uses HDMI)

I have an NVIDIA 2070s video card so I went into NVIDIA X Server Settings which is supposed to control all of that, gave it root permissions, and made sure the xorg file contained the correct defaults. After that I double checked the content of the file itself and it looks correct, but the problem persists.

I confirmed the problem only occurs when using these monitors and that it only happens when I boot to Ubuntu, it works fine on Windows. At this point I'm at a loss for where to go from here. Anyone know where this problem could be coming from or any workarounds to fix it? Even a vague idea of where to look next would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried temporarily switching to XOrg Nouveau drivers instead of Nvidia? If you don't get the issue like that then it would hint that the problem is something to do with the Nvidia settings or drivers. I have a similar setup (was 20.04, now 20.10 but always was one monitor via HDMI and one via via DisplayPort and no issues). I don't use Nvidia drivers though.

Comment: @codlord Forgive my inexperience, but I am not sure how to do that and most of the resources I can find about Nouveau xorg are from 2010 or earlier and don't seem applicable. Do you know where I could find more info about this? Thanks

Comment: Open `Software Updater` app and click the `Settings` button. Or alternatively open the `Software & Updates` app which should get you to the same window. Then go to the `Additional Drivers` tab. Assuming you have a proprietary driver selected, scroll to bottom and select the `Nouveau (open source)` option. Then press the `Apply Changes` button.

Comment: @codlord I switched drivers and restarted. I'm now getting 2/3s black screen and a tiled repeating pattern of what should be the top left corner of the screen going across the bottom. The picture does not update and I cannot interact with it. I was apparently able top login because my keyboard started running its LED software after I entered my password but nothing visibly updated

Comment: @codlord So with this post we managed to make the problem worse and get ghosted. What an outstanding community. Guess I'll figure it out on my own.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Kyle Not entirely. I got the driver fixed by restarting in safe mode and changing the driver back, but I still have the single-screen problem. I've started just turning the left monitor off and back on which fixes it, it's just annoying that I have to do that every time